# E: unable to locate the package oversip

Tags: server

I got this error

```
E: unable to locate the package oversip
```

when I write this command

```
sudo apt-get install oversip
```

Comment: I want to know why this error comes.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you already add the repository of oversip?!

So first of all you have to add the repository. Edit your **/etc/apt/sources.list** file (or create a new file **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oversip.list**) and add the appropriate line for your Ubuntu distribution:

Ubuntu 12.04 Precise:

```
deb http://deb.versatica.com precise main
```

Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal:

```
deb http://deb.versatica.com quantal main
```

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring:

```
deb http://deb.versatica.com raring main
```

Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr:

```
deb http://deb.versatica.com trusty main
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install

```
sudo apt-get install oversip
```

Comment: yes i have added the repository..

Comment: after running this(sudo apt-get install oversip) command i got the error

Comment: E: unable to locate the package oversip

Comment: did u make sudo apt-get update?

Comment: @kalpityadav Yes, you must to run `sudo apt-get update` to update the package list **first** before you try to install. Otherwise, oversip will not be included and so cannot be found.

Comment: i did this also.\

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://deb.versatica.com trusty main'
wget -O - http://deb.versatica.com/deb.versatica.com.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oversip
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://deb.versatica.com precise main'
wget -O - http://deb.versatica.com/deb.versatica.com.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oversip
```